# Formatting almost a json-file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm reading from a file with the content:

> {"quotes":["I could calculate your chance of survival, but you won't like it.","I'd give you advice, but you wouldn't listen. No one ever does.","I ache, therefore I am.","I've seen it. It's rubbish. (About a Magrathean sunset that Arthur finds magnificent)","Not that anyone cares what I say, but the Restaurant is on the other end of the universe.","I think you ought to know I'm feeling very depressed.","My capacity for happiness,\" he added, \"you could fit into a matchbox without taking out the matches first.","Arthur: \"Marvin, any ideas?\" Marvin: \"I have a million ideas. They all point to certain death.\"","\"What's up?\" [asked Ford.] \"I don't know,\" said Marvin, \"I've never been there.\"","Marvin: \"I am at a rough estimate thirty billion times more intelligent than you. Let me give you an example. Think of a number, any number.\" Zem: \"Er, five.\" Marvin: \"Wrong. You see?\"","Zaphod: \"Can it Trillian, I'm trying to die with dignity. Marvin: \"I'm just trying to die.\""]}*

As you can see it's almost a json-file but with additional characters like: [\ .

**Task**: Formate content of the file so I can access separate quotes and print out random quotes.

I could try something like this

```
jsonfile = open(INPUT, "r")
jsonobject = json.load(jsonfile)
someString = "\n\"{quotes}\"\n".format(quotes=jsonobject["quotes"])
```

which will get rid of {quotes:} from the string. Though additional unwanted characters remain and I have tried using `string.replace` separately and in a loop but it doesn't give me the result I want.

Example: `holder = someString.replace("[\]", '')`

After the formatting is done I guess I should use a loop and try the random module with `random.string`?

Comment: Actually... that is valid json that gives you a dict with a list of quotes. For instance, `data["quotes"][0]` is `"I could calculate your ch ance of survival, but you won't like it."`. You get those ` \ ` escape characters because the json strings have embeded strings.

Comment: BTW, its great to see that you have quotes from some of the world's greatest literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have valid JSON data *already*. `\"` is an escaped quote (so it is part of the string value), and `[...]` is a JSON *array* (analogous to a Python list).

Just load your data as JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> jsondata = r'''{"quotes":["I could calculate your chance of survival, but you won't like it.","I'd give you advice, but you wouldn't listen. No one ever does.","I ache, therefore I am.","I've seen it. It's rubbish. (About a Magrathean sunset that Arthur finds magnificent)","Not that anyone cares what I say, but the Restaurant is on the other end of the universe.","I think you ought to know I'm feeling very depressed.","My capacity for happiness,\" he added, \"you could fit into a matchbox without taking out the matches first.","Arthur: \"Marvin, any ideas?\" Marvin: \"I have a million ideas. They all point to certain death.\"","\"What's up?\" [asked Ford.] \"I don't know,\" said Marvin, \"I've never been there.\"","Marvin: \"I am at a rough estimate thirty billion times more intelligent than you. Let me give you an example. Think of a number, any number.\" Zem: \"Er, five.\" Marvin: \"Wrong. You see?\"","Zaphod: \"Can it Trillian, I'm trying to die with dignity. Marvin: \"I'm just trying to die.\""]}'''
 >>> data = json.loads(jsondata)
 >>> data
 {'quotes': ["I could calculate your chance of survival, but you won't like it.", "I'd give you advice, but you wouldn't listen. No one ever does.", 'I ache, therefore I am.', "I've seen it. It's rubbish. (About a Magrathean sunset that Arthur finds magnificent)", 'Not that anyone cares what I say, but the Restaurant is on the other end of the universe.', "I think you ought to know I'm feeling very depressed.", 'My capacity for happiness," he added, "you could fit into a matchbox without taking out the matches first.', 'Arthur: "Marvin, any ideas?" Marvin: "I have a million ideas. They all point to certain death."', '"What\'s up?" [asked Ford.] "I don\'t know," said Marvin, "I\'ve never been there."', 'Marvin: "I am at a rough estimate thirty billion times more intelligent than you. Let me give you an example. Think of a number, any number." Zem: "Er, five." Marvin: "Wrong. You see?"', 'Zaphod: "Can it Trillian, I\'m trying to die with dignity. Marvin: "I\'m just trying to die."']}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
{'quotes': ["I could calculate your chance of survival, but you won't like it.",
            "I'd give you advice, but you wouldn't listen. No one ever does.",
            'I ache, therefore I am.',
            "I've seen it. It's rubbish. (About a Magrathean sunset that "
            'Arthur finds magnificent)',
            'Not that anyone cares what I say, but the Restaurant is on the '
            'other end of the universe.',
            "I think you ought to know I'm feeling very depressed.",
            'My capacity for happiness," he added, "you could fit into a '
            'matchbox without taking out the matches first.',
            'Arthur: "Marvin, any ideas?" Marvin: "I have a million ideas. '
            'They all point to certain death."',
            '"What\'s up?" [asked Ford.] "I don\'t know," said Marvin, "I\'ve '
            'never been there."',
            'Marvin: "I am at a rough estimate thirty billion times more '
            'intelligent than you. Let me give you an example. Think of a '
            'number, any number." Zem: "Er, five." Marvin: "Wrong. You see?"',
            'Zaphod: "Can it Trillian, I\'m trying to die with dignity. '
            'Marvin: "I\'m just trying to die."']}
>>> import random
>>> print(random.choice(data['quotes']))
I've seen it. It's rubbish. (About a Magrathean sunset that Arthur finds magnificent)
>>> print(random.choice(data['quotes']))
I ache, therefore I am.
```

In the above demo I used the [`random.choice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick one of the quotes from the list at random.

The only thing missing is Marvin's lullaby, my favourite of all Marvin's utterings:

> Now the world has gone to bed
>   Darkness won't engulf my head
>   I can see by infra-red
>   How I hate the night
>
> Now I lay me down to sleep
>   Try to count electric sheep
>   Sweet dream wishes you can keep
>   How I hate the night

Answer (score 0):

This should work as is.

```
import json
import random
file = open(<path to your file>,'r')
i = json.load(file)
#print a random quote
print i['quotes'][int(random.randrange(0,len(i['quotes'])-1))]
```